# Comparing columns value of a CSV file

Tags: python, calculated-columns

I have a csv file of ten tags in 10 rows and 3 columns . How do I write python code to compare column 1 value more or less then column 2 and column 3 values. This condition should be applicable to all rows.

Comment: Share the csv and the current code you have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The code depends on the details of your CSV file.
For example if the csv is the following one:

```
$ cat data.csv 
C1,C2,C3
4,5,6
9,8,7
6,5,4
3,2,1
```

you can use this pseudo-code to analyse the data:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', mode ='r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        if (compare(row['C1'], row['C2'], row['C3']):
            do_something()
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark icon @Ary